# Where does deployment for stage in Amazon API Gateway come from?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

When I create a stage in API Gateway, I need to set the deployment date. When I click the drop down, there are a couple of dates listed in there but I don't know how were they generated. I can't even write the date manually, so I am just wondering where do the items in the list come from anyway?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [AWS API Gateway docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stages.html) - "From the Deployment drop-down list, choose the date and time of the existing API deployment you want to associate with this stage.".

When you create a stage, you will see all the deployments (and switch between them) in the Deployment History tab for stage. So it's more of a read-only list that represent moments when you did [deployments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api.html) to API Gateway.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I get it now. The deployment date is created when I am deploying the API. Never noticed that step before. I thought that when I am creating the stage I am already deploying the API. Anyway, thanks!